# React Webpack and a server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server, backend

I am really confused with the [react-webpack](https://github.com/newtriks/generator-react-webpack) stack. The more I read online, the more confused I get.

I am simply trying to call an API and get data into my component such as this:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';

require('styles//ListCard.scss');

class ListCardComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="list-card">
        <div className="list-card-details">
          <p>{this.props.title}</p>
          <p>{this.props.content}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ListCardComponent.displayName = 'ListCardComponent';

export default ListCardComponent;
```

I currently have a backend `localhost:3000` that I can call for JSON data.
My react app is running on `localhost:8000`. How do I connect properly connect these two to work together?

Comment: The react webpack stack has become a confusing  jungle!
I just put some very basic boilerplates together, maybe they will help you: https://github.com/cheesyeyes/react-junglebook

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is three ways:

- Use [json-p](http://json-p.org/)
- Allow [CORS](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/) on the server
- Configure your backend to serve static and dynamic content

Answer (score 0):

Webpack is a build tool that lets you process assets (source files, images, stylesheets) into another form. It's basically an extremely flexible compile step that lets you do more powerful tasks than were possible with Grunt or Gulp. It has nothing to do with serving your code or backend.

If you have data on `localhost:3000` and a React app on `localhost:8000`, you need to use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).